# Lync error: waitall for multiple handles on a STA threads is not supported

Tags: powershell, lync-2010

I'm trying to export IM chats logs from my Lync archive server. I've followed the instructions detailed at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh328432.aspx.

When I issue my command:

```
export-CSArchivingData -DBInstance <sqlserername> -StartDate 12/31/12 -EndDate 01/03/13 -OutputFolder "C:\SJS" -UserURI <emailaddress>
```

I get the following error:

```
export-CSArchivingData : WaitAll for multiple handles on a STA thread is not supported.
At line:1 char:1
+ export-CSArchivingData -DBInstance <sqlservername> -StartDate 12/31/12 -EndDate 01/ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Rtc.A...ArchiveDataImpl:ExportArchiveDataImpl) [Export-CsArchivingData], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : export-CSArchivingData,ExportArchiveData.ExportArchiveDataCmdlet
```

and no records are returned. Any ideas? This is Lync 2010 and I'm running this command from the administrator lync server management shell. I have full admin rights on the lync server machine and the sql server where the logs are stored.

Comment: Oops..looks like some of my command was edited out. I do specify a server name for DBInstance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same error exporting from my Lync server. It seemed too similar to this issue with Exchange server and the latest WMF 3.0 release:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/12/14/windows-management-framework-3-0-on-exchange-2007-and-exchange-2010.aspx

So I uninstalled the KB2506143 update and restarted the Lync server. Magically I was able to export from the archive once again.
Cheers,

Comment: Thanks. I don't see an option to uninstall that from my server, but it does show up on the list of installed updates, so this could be the cause of my problem too.

Comment: Got the KB2506143 patch uninstalled and now the export is working. Thanks!!